# Is it possible to create a vector of a template class and call its functions?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, inheritance

I created a template class with some methods that use as parameter template type like this:

```
template <class T>
class vector{
... 
void new(const T&new_value)
...
}
```

I want to use it inside another class but since it's not allowed to declare it like this:

```
class matrix{
vector *_ptr_to_vect;
}
```

I created a base class `BaseVector`.

But in `BaseVector` I cannot define a virtual function like `new(const T&new_value)` to override it (because I don't want to use template again). Since I cannot define it then is not possible to call it like:

```
BaseVector _ptr_to_vect;
BaseVector[0].new("new value")
```

Comment: Defining a `new` function is really going to mess with people that expect operator `new`, not function `new`. Any other name would be better.

Comment: When you use your template class you need to give it a type, like `vector<std::string>` or something. You can't leave it ambiguous.

Comment: `new` is also not a valid name for a function.

Comment: `new` is a language keyword, so cannot be used as a function name.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a base class. You need to make `matrix` a template:

```
template <class T>
class matrix{
    vector<T> _ptr_to_vect;
};
```

Alternately if your matrix class is always of one type (let's say `float` for instance):

```
class matrix{
    vector<float> _ptr_to_vect;
};
```

Comment: The problem is I want a matrix with different types. For example 1st column of integers, 2nd column of float and so on

Comment: @pipespups then you can't do that with pure templates. If you have a fixed set of types, you might be able to used std::variant https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant to allow you to construct a type that can hold any value in the set which you can put in your vector.

Answer (score 0):

Author's comment:

> The problem is I want a matrix with different types. For example 1st column of integers, 2nd column of float and so on

In pure C++11 you might use a bit template magic for this purpose:

```cpp
//
// Lightweight wrapper over any type
//
template<typename T>
struct identity {
    using type = T;
};

//
// Metafunction that converts type T
// into vector<T>
//
template<typename T>
struct add_vector {
    using type = vector<T>;
};

//
// Function used to obtain std::tuple<vector<Types>>
// type from Types
//
template<typename... Types>
constexpr auto make_tuple_of_vectors()
{
    return identity<
        std::tuple< add_vector<Types>::type... >
    >{};
}

//
// Our matrix, it receives types of all its
// columns as template parameters
//
template<typename... ColumnTypes>
class matrix
{
    using matrix_internal_t = decltype(
        make_tuple_of_vectors<ColumnTypes...>
    )::type;

    static constexpr size_t columns_count = 
        sizeof...( Types );

public:
    // Don't know why you need a pointer here
    // It's better to store a value maybe
    matrix_internal_t* matrix_ptr;
};
```

This solution allows you to store different types in different columns. The problem is only with indexation. You must know at compile-time an index of column you want to get access.

You can provide following member-function:

```cpp
template<size_t column_index>
auto get_column()
{
    static_assert(
        column_index < columns_count,
        "Out of range"
    );

    return std::get<column_index>( *matrix_ptr );
}
```

In each column got by following method you can use `[]` operator.

Usage:

```cpp
matrix<int, float, double> m;

// Get the first column (with integers)
auto v1 = m.get_column<0>();

// Get the second column (with floats)
auto v2 = m.get_column<1>();

// Get 4'th column, that doesn't exist
// Raises compilation error
// auto v4 = m.get_column<3>();
```

To get access to ij'th element more elegant, you may define a macro:

```cpp
// j must be known at compile-time
#define get_element( matrix, i, j ) matrix.get_column<j>()[i]
```

For iteration over columns you may write own `for_each`, but a bit more complicated: try to find an implementation of `for_aech` for tuple or write it by yourself :)
Writing such algorithm is a good practice